# ¿Cómo graficar la función piso en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

Estoy tratando de hacer la gráfica de la función y = floor(2x-1) con los círculos en cada extremo para denotar el intervalo cerrado-abierto en **Python**. Inicialmente estaba pensando en hacer algo así usando las bibliotecas **numpy** y **matplotlib**.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(-5,5,0.5)
y = np.floor((2*x)-1)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Sin embargo, no obtengo la gráfica deseada, en cambio, se genera una gráfica lineal con pendiente positiva. He usado otras variaciones pero aún así no logro obtener la gráfica correcta de la función. Gracias por su ayuda :)

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! podrias aclarar como queres la grafica, y como te esta quedando?

Comment: No se comprende si no logras graficar, o lo logras pero lo que graficas no es lo que buscas. De ser el primer intenta cambiar el import de numpy a: import numpy as np, de todos modos debrías editar la consulta para que se comprenda.

Comment: La gráfica me está dando como si fuera una función lineal, pero debería dar una gráfica a trozos, tal y como la función parte entera, sólo que con algunas traslaciones.

Answer (score 2):

Para la función que escoges y el rango de x, da la casualidad que todos los números en `y` son únicos, si escoges un menor **step** en `np.arange` podemos ver los pasos que da la función.

```
x = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.2)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta gráfica `lineal` ocurre por el estilo de dibujo que define como se conectan estos puntos por defecto, o sea usando lineas rectas, por eso podemos ver lineas rectas conectando los escalones.

Podemos darle una mejor presentación a la gráfica usando una propiedad de dibujo llamada `drawstyle` y para el caso de la función `np.floor` usamos *steps-post*.

```
plt.plot(x, y, drawstyle='steps-post')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te dejo el enlace a esta propiedad en la documentación para que puedas revisar mas a profundidad. [drawstyle](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_drawstyle)